# Output an environment variable from a JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, java-8

I need to output the value of an environment variable from within a JSP.  It works correctly when trying from a Servlet, but the same code in a JSP fails to compile.  I get "java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved".  My environment is jdk1.8.0_05 32-bit, Eclipse EE Kepler 32-bit, WebLogic 10.3.6.

Servlet I tried:

```
out.append(System.getenv("VOLED_BASE_HREF"))
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
response.getWriter().print(out.toString());
```

And that works fine.  But when I try this in a simple JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    out.print(System.getenv("VOLED_BASE_HREF"));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I get:

```
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP /index.jsp
index.jsp:11:12: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    out.print(System.getenv("VOLED_BASE_HREF"));
                  ^-----------------------------^

    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.reportCompilationErrorIfNeccessary(JavelinxJSPStub.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage(JavelinxJSPStub.java:162)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:256)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspStub.prepareServlet(JspStub.java:216)
```

Comment: have you tried adding an explicit JSP import for java.util.Map$Entry?

Comment: Have you forget to import `<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>` in JSP?

Comment: This has nothing to do with imports; `java.util.Map$Entry` is a fully qualified class name. For whatever reason, it looks like the WebLogic server doesn't know about it at all--perhaps its executing JRE is bad or refers to inner classes differently? Can you try a more recent version?

Comment: WebLogic does not support Java 8. Most probably, the interface `Map.Entry` is there but the JSP compiler can’t read it due to the newer class file format. Note that `Map.Entry` has `static` methods now, a feature which was not supported in older Java versions.

Comment: Have you tried executing this using JDK 7 or another JDK 8 distribution?

Comment: I'll give JDK7 a try and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holger had it, this doesn't work in JDK8, I had to run the server under JDK7.  For anyone else who runs into this, to switch JDK versions go into WLDOMAIN\bin and edit setDomainEnv.cmd (or setDomainEnv.sh) and point it to another JDK installation.